# Search function in my leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I am trying to have a search function that will search through my geojson file. The geojson file was upload successfully.I used one of the examples I found here, my problem is this error :
Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.Search is not a constructor

I did reference the leaflet library, please help what am I missing.

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> My Leaflet.js Map  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css " /> 

    <script
    src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ecngoc_members_json.geojson"></script>

    <style>
     html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
    </style>

         <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var osmLink = "<a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org'>Open StreetMap</a>"                                     
             var map =L.map('map').setView([-29.436487, 24.854498],6);
             L.tileLayer(
                 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                  attribution: 'Map data &copy; ' + osmLink,
                   maxZoom: 14,
                  }).addTo(map);

        /*  var ngodata = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Organisati": "Dikeni Disabled Self Help Ass", "Sector 1": "Disabled", "Physical A": "5 Grey Lane Street", "Town": "Alice", "Province": "Eastern Cape", "Country": "South Africa", "addrtype": "route", "addrlocat": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER", "POINT_X": 26.6390371, "POINT_Y": -32.767646 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.6390371, -32.767646 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Organisati": "The Holy Nation of God", "Sector 1": "HIV AIDS", "Physical A": "150 Ntselamanzi Township", "Town": "Alice", "Province": "Eastern Cape", "Country": "South Africa", "addrtype": "locality", "addrlocat": "APPROXIMATE", "POINT_X": 26.8329509, "POINT_Y": -32.7901325 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.8329509, -32.7901325 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Organisati": "Alice Business Forum", "Sector 1": "Community Development", "Physical A": "19 Wienand Street", "Town": "Alice", "Province": "Eastern Cape", "Country": "South Africa", "addrtype": "street_address", "addrlocat": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED", "POINT_X": 26.8300864, "POINT_Y": -32.7874356 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.8300864, -32.7874356 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Organisati": "Isolomzi Community Health Organisation", "Sector 1": "Health Welfare", "Physical A": "48 Frere Street", "Town": "Alicedale", "Province": "Eastern Cape", "Country": "South Africa", "addrtype": "locality", "addrlocat": "APPROXIMATE", "POINT_X": 26.0738958, "POINT_Y": -33.3164948 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 26.0738958, -33.3164948 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Organisati": "Barkley East Advice Office", "Sector 1": "Paralegal Human Rights", "Physical A": "727 Dale Street", "Town": "Barkly East", "Province": "Eastern Cape", "Country": "South Africa", "addrtype": "route", "addrlocat": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER", "POINT_X": 27.5961071, "POINT_Y": -30.9674799 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 27.5961071, -30.9674799 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Organisati": "People fighting Gender based violence", "Sector 1": "Gender", "Physical A": "11 Rhahabe Road", "Town": "Bisho", "Province": "Eastern Cape", "Country": "South Africa", "addrtype": "locality", "addrlocat": "APPROXIMATE", "POINT_X": 27.4409557, "POINT_Y": -32.849876 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 27.4409557, -32.849876 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Organisati": "Khanyisa Comm Educare Development Centre", "Sector 1": "Educare", "Physical A": "Zone 6 Old Government Offices, Zwelitsha", "Town": "Bisho", "Province": "Eastern Cape", "Country": "South Africa", "addrtype": "locality", "addrlocat": "APPROXIMATE", "POINT_X": 27.4409557, "POINT_Y": -32.849876 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 27.4409557, -32.849876 ] } },
]
} */

    //code to add geoJson data in the map and display the points.
    /*var layer = L.geoJson(ngodata, {
     //style: myStyle
     }).addTo(map);*/

    //create empty geoJson layer to be populated later
//styles, popups and other layer options can be specified here
var ngoLayer = L.geoJson(false, {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {};
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Organisati);
    }
});

//load GeoJSON data, add it to the layer
$.getJSON("http://localhost/configureSearch/tryGeojson/ecngoc_members_json.geojson", function (data) {
    // add GeoJSON data to layer and add to the map once the file is loaded
    ngoLayer.addData(data).addTo(map);
}); 

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
    layer: ngoLayer,
    propertyName: 'name',
    circleLocation: false
});

searchControl.on('search_locationfound', function (e) {

    e.layer.setStyle({
        fillColor: '#3f0',
        color: '#0f0'
    });
    if (e.layer._popup) e.layer.openPopup();

}).on('search_collapsed', function (e) {

    ngoLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) { //restore feature color
        ngoLayer.resetStyle(layer);
    });
});

map.addControl(searchControl); //inizialize search control
        }//end function
    </script> 

</head>
<body onload=init()>
<div id="map"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leaflet 0.7 doesn't have a Search control built in. You need to include one from the Leaflet plugins, which means an extra bit of JS to include.

I guess you are probably trying to use this one:

https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search

see the documentation and examples for how to include and use the plugin.